# calling DB from javascript throwing error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have a simple php page postArticle.php with two dropdown list with categories and subcategories and subcategories generates on the basis of categories.

for generating subcategories i am using java script from which i am calling another php file(data.php)

the code postarticle.php is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function getSubCategories(l1,l2)
            {
                var response;
                var xmlHttp;
                if(l1.selectedIndex>=1)
                    {
                        try{
                            var id=document.getElementById('listCategory').value;
                        //alert("hello "+id);
                        l2.disabled=false;
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                          var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        else
                        {// code for IE6, IE5
                           var xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        //alert("hello 1");
                        xmlHttp.open("POST","data.php?q="+id,true);
                        //alert("id passed is : " +id);
                        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){
                        //alert("inside fn1");          

                        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                        {
                        //alert("inside if fun");                       
                        //alert(xmlHttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);
                        //alert("response text : "+xmlHttp.responseText);
                        response=xmlHttp.responseText;
                        }

                        //alert("inside fn2");
                        }

                        //alert("hello 3");
                        xmlHttp.send("data.jsp?q="+id);
                        //alert('hello 4');

                        var resArray=new Array();
                        //alert('hello 5');
                        response=response.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                         resArray=response.split("#");
                        //alert('hello 6');
                        //alert("response array : "+resArray);
                        for(x in resArray)
                            {
                                //alert(resArray[x].substring(0, resArray[x].indexOf("*")));
                                //alert(resArray[x].substring(resArray[x].indexOf("*")+1));
                                if(resArray[x].substring(0, resArray[x].indexOf("*"))!=" " && resArray[x].substring(resArray[x].indexOf("*")+1)!="")
                                    {
                                var OptNew = document.createElement('option');
                                OptNew.text = resArray[x].substring(resArray[x].indexOf("*")+1);
                                OptNew.value = resArray[x].substring(0, resArray[x].indexOf("*"));
                                try
                                  {
                                    //for IE earlier than version 8
                                    l2.add(OptNew,l2.options[null]);
                                  }
                                catch (e)
                                  {
                                    l2.add(option,null);
                                  }
                                    }
                            }
            }catch(e){alert(e.toString());}
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            return;
                        }


                var newOpt = new Option(selText[i], selValues[i]);
                theSel.options[i] = newOpt;

            }
        </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr id="header" >
                <td height="30%" width="100%" colspan="3">
<?php include("Header.php"); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="body">
                <td height="65%" width="15%" valign="center">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr><td>
<?php include("LeftPanel.php"); ?>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td height="65%" width="75%" valign="center">
                        <form method="post" action="PostArticle_Back.php">
                        Title: <input type="text" name="txtTitle" id="txtTitle">
                        <br>
                        Content : <textarea id="txtContent" name="txtContent" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <p>select Category :</p>
                        <select id="listCategory" name="listCategory" onchange="getSubCategories(listCategory,listSubCategory)">
                            <option value="0">Select Category</option>
                            <?php
                                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                                if(!$con)
                                {
                                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                }       
                                mysql_select_db("articles_db",$con);
                                $result = mysql_query("select CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME from TBL_CATEGORIES");

                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                  {
                             ?>
                           <option value="<?php  echo $row['CATEGORY_ID'] ; ?>" > <?php  echo $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] ; ?>
                                </option>
                                <?php } ?>

                        </select>

                        <br>
                        <p>select SubCategory :</p>
                        <select id="listSubCategory" name="listSubCategory" disabled="true">
                            <option value="0">select Subcategory</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post Article"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td height="65%" width="10%" valign="center">
                    Right panel
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="footer">
                <td height="5%" colspan="3">
                    Footer
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

but it throws an error
**TypeError :  undefined is null or not an object**

the problem what i find till now is that the data.php is taking time to send response

if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) is taking time to execute.

because when i add alert statements in between code it works fine.

what i tried till now:

1. i tried to add while loop outside if condition but broweser gives a warning : 
   **script is making your webpage slow**
2. i tried to put the code(the code for adding repose to drop down list) in if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) condition but it did not gave any response.

Comment: try adding xmlHttp.status 200, status 200 means OK! `if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)` and "4"  complete, all data downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tip 1

I don't really get what that is your problem, but if you need to wait to get the value you can use `Async=false`.

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "data.php?q="+ id, false);
```

Then you dont need the `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){ ... }`, the code will wait for the response, and the rest of the Javascript will stop execute until the response is fetched.

### Tip 2

If you still want other Javascript code to execute `(Async = true)` you can put

```
               var resArray=new Array();
                //alert('hello 5');
                response=response.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                 resArray=response.split("#");
                 ...more code...

                            }
                    }
```

in the `xmlHttp.readyState == 4` block.

```
               if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                {
                     response=xmlHttp.responseText;
                     //Put the code here
                }
```

I had done like this.

### Other things

Why do you use "POST"? You dont send any POST data.
`xmlHttp.send("data.jsp?q="+id);` should be `xmlHttp.send("q="+id);` if you want to fetch `$_POST['q']`. But you already send id like an GET request in `xmlHttp.open("POST","data.php?q="+id,true);`, so why send it again with POST?

And please indent your code correctly.

_

*Btw, what is AJAX without Asynchronousing? Javascript And XML? :P*

***EDIT:**
Yay, my first "Correct answer" :)*

Comment: Thanks sawny..

it worked 

what silly mistake i made,
call should async always

Comment: It'd be SJAX: synchronous javascript and xml. Not quite as catchy, and would make 'comet' not make much sense as a name.